# How to print multiple "for loops" on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code.

```
item = stock.stock_list(location)        

for lists in sorted(item):
    print ("{:<20}".format(lists))

for price in sorted(item): 
    print("{:>8.2f}".format(stock_price(price)))

for qty in sorted(item): 
    print("{:>6}".format(stock.stock_quantity(location, qty))
```

and it prints out,

```
Beetroot            
Black-eyed peas     
Cassava             
Greater plantain    
Pak choy           
17.03
11.98
11.61
10.09
92
94
76
67
```

i need it to print out on the same line, like so.

```
Beetroot             17.03       94
Black-eyed peas      11.98       92
Cassava              43.21       76
Greater plantain     12.45       43
Pak choy             19.22       43
```

don't worry about the numbers.
and it has to be aligned like so,

```
  "{:<20}{:>8.2f}{:>6}".format
```

Comment: `for lists, price,qty in sorted(items):`

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: i need it to print out like its shown on the 3rd code.

Comment: Each loop iterates through the same iterable, so `lists`, `price`, and `qty` are all the same thing - I don't think `for lists, price, qty in sorted(items)` would apply in this case. It might be more appropriate to use `for element in sorted(items): print(element, stock_price(element), stock_quantity(location, element))`, with proper formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Just use one loop:

```
for i in sorted(item):
    print("{:<20}{:>8.2f}{:>6}".format(i, 
                                       stock_price(i), 
                                       stock.stock_quantity(location, i))
```

You probably want a better name than `i` but this is just whiteboard code

Answer (score 1):

I think is is what you are after (dummy code):

```
import random

item = ['Beetroot',           
   'Black-eyed peas',   
   'Cassava',           
   'Greater plantain'    
   'Pak choy']


for an_item in sorted(item):
    stoc_price     = random.randint(1,10)
    stock_quantity = random.randint(1,10)
    print("{:<30}{:>8.2f}{:>6}".format(an_item, stoc_price, stock_quantity))
```

Gives:

```
Beetroot                          5.00     1
Black-eyed peas                   2.00     8
Cassava                           1.00     5
Greater plantainPak choy          6.00     9
```